# Pandas append is adding columns for some reason

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am not sure what is going on with my code, so perhaps someone can give me a hand.

Essentially I am making different dataframes from a large csv file, where each dataframe is made up of different columns from an original csv file. My code looks something like this (where the variable `name` is defined in `listoflists` as the name of a particular list and where this is all taking place in a for loop iterating over `name` and `i`):

```
if name is table1 and all([m in df_allcol.columns for m in listoflists[0][i]):
    df_new = df_allcol[listoflists[0][i]]
    df_table1 = df_table1.append(df_new)
    df_table1.to_csv(filepath, index = False)
```

My issue is that this works perfectly without the `append` line (if I just write `df_new` to a csv). But once I add `append`, it adds column headers from another table into the dataframe. The columns are empty (just the headers are there), but they are there for some reason. I guess I don't understand exactly what append is doing to be accessing another table.

Without append (just sending `df_new` to a csv):

```
column2    column3    column6
 data1      data1      data1
   .          .          .
   .          .          .
 dataN      dataN      dataN
```

With append (sending `df_table1` to a csv):

```
column1    column2    column3    column4    column5    column6
            data1      data1                            data1
              .          .                                .
              .          .                                .
            dataN      dataN                            dataN
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use axis = 0 in you append function like below and you will get the desired result.

```
df_table1 = df_table1.append(df_new, axis=0)
```

Comment: If I do that, then I get an "unexpected keyword argument" error on 'axis'.

Comment: After you are out of the loop, collecting everything in df_table1, try the vstack like below. Hope it works if not please help me with some sample data for your question to help you. stacked  = np.vstack(df_table1)